# Will AWS S3 event forwarding to SQS will end up being a different message than S3 to SNS to SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, splunk

I am using a Splunk Technical Add-on that will be pulling messages from an SQS queue. Although the TA suggests using S3 forwarding to an SNS and it subscribed to an SQS, there is also the possibility of S3 to forward directly to SQS.

Would SNS make any change on what S3 send to it? Or would it be a fully transparent transport method to SQS?

Comment: You can try it and find out. Create an S3 bucket, an SNS topic and an SQS queue. First, configure the S3 event to send to SQS and upload an object. For the second test, subscribe the SQS queue to the SNS topic, configure the S3 event to send to SNS and upload an object. Then, check to see if the results are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default, S3 → SQS and S3 → SNS → SQS will result in two different data structures/formats inside the SQS message body.

This is because an SNS subscription provides [metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html) with each message delivered -- the SNS `MessageId`, a `Signature` to validate authenticity, a `Timestamp` of when SNS originally accepted the message, and other attributes.  The original message is encoded as a JSON string inside the `Message` attribute of this outer JSON structure.

So with SQS direct, you would extract the S3 event with (pseudocode)...

```
s3event = JSON.parse(sqsbody)
```

...but with SNS to SQS...

```
s3event = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(sqsbody).Message)
```

You can disable the additional structures and have SNS send only the original payload by enabling *raw message delivery* on the SQS subscription to the SNS topic.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html

With raw message delivery enabled, the contents become the same, for both S3 → SQS and S3 → SNS → SQS.

The downside to raw message delivery is that you lose potentially useful troubleshooting information with raw message delivery, like the SNS message ID and SNS-issued timestamp.

On the other hand, if the receiving service (the SQS consumer) assumes the messages are always coming via SNS and expects to find the SNS data structure in the SQS message body, then sending direct S3 → SQS will result in the consumer finding that the message body from SQS does not match its expectations.

Comment: Right it makes sense to me, and I will indeed check the Python code of the Splunk TA to understand if the expected is the raw part or the whole one.